# How to get comma separated values in td

Tags: php

i getting values from query but i have to place them as comma separated values if there is more than one value
I'm looking for output like this:
     title   (x,y) , (x,y)

Please help me how can i do this i'm trying in function to get this

```
$cols = array ('test.*', 'user.*', 'count(test_stats.test_public_id) as 
past_day_views','test_stats.test_public_id', 'test_stats.*' );
$select = $db->select () ->from ( 'test', $cols )
    ->join ( 'user', 'user.user_id = test.user_id', array () )
    ->join ( 'test_stats', 'test_stats.test_public_id = test.test_public_id', array ())
    ->where ( 'test_stats.updated_on > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)' )
    ->group ( 'test_stats.test_public_id' )
    ->order ( 'title' );
    $result = $db->fetchAll ( $select );
foreach ( $result as $row1 ) {
    $x = $row1 ['x'] ;
    $y = $row1 ['y'];
    $z = $row1 ['title'];
}
```

Comment: Do you just want to echo it?
EDIT: You could use <? echo $z. "(". $x. ",". $y. ")"; ?>

Comment: i want to write them in a separate function and then call it in table row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have used this in query

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT  test_stats.xy SEPARATOR '<br/>') as x
```