# How to echo specific multiple same records only once using foreach loops in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

I have these output using foreach loop in PHP. Right now the output inside foreach is like below.

PHP code

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ACCOUNT NUMBER</th>
      <th>CATEGORY</th>
      <th>AMOUNT</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      $sqlTxt = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 'Fruits' ";
      $sql = ORACLE::getInstance()->FetchArray($sqlTxt);
      if(count($sql) > 0)
      {
        foreach($sql as $row)
        {
    ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row["ACCOUNT_NUMBER"] ;?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["CATEGORY"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $row["AMOUNT"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        }
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the output for above code is like this

```
Account Number          Category            Amount
1001                    Apple               30.00
1001                    Mango               30.00
1001                    Blueberry           30.00 

1002                    Durian              40.00
1002                    Pineapple           40.00
1002                    Jackfruit           40.00 
1002                    Lime                40.00

1003                    Lemon               50.00
1003                    Orange              50.00
```

My questions is how can I echo **Account Number** and **Amount** one time only while category keeps the looping ?

My goal is to look like this. To add br tag after each comas.

```
Account Number          Category            Amount
1001                    Apple,              30.00
                        Mango,              
                        Blueberry            

1002                    Durian,             40.00
                        Pineapple,          
                        Jackfruit,           
                        Lime                

1003                    Lemon,              50.00
                        Orange
```

So far, what I have in my code is like this.

PHP Code

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ACCOUNT NUMBER</th>
      <th>CATEGORY</th>
      <th>AMOUNT</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      $sqlTxt = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = 'Fruits' ";
      $sql = ORACLE::getInstance()->FetchArray($sqlTxt);
      if(count($sql) > 0)
      {
        $account_numbers = null;
        $categorys       = "";
        $amounts         = null;

        foreach($sql as $row)
        {
          if($row['ACCOUNT_NUMBER'] !== $account_numbers)
          {
            if ($account_numbers !== null)
            {
              echo '</td></tr>';
            }

            echo "<tr>
                    <td>{$row['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']}</td>
                    <td>{$row['CATEGORY']}";
          }
          else {
            echo "<br>{$selectionC['CATEGORY']}";
          }
          $account_numbers = $row['ACCOUNT_NUMBER'];
        }
            echo '  </td>
                  </tr>';
      }
    ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm stuck here. Appreciate if someone can help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: @mickmackusa . Thank you for the feedback . If you don't mind, can you show it to an answer ? thanks again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10332417/2943403 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/51697336/2943403 (if doing more processing inside the loop)

Comment: @mickmackusa . It work for new line. Thanks. But still one issue left which is to merge/group multiple records into one output only.

Comment: This is a very simply _control break_ you want to implement here. All you need to do, is compare the current account number with the previous one - if it is different, you output it, otherwise you don’t.

Comment: @CBroe. Thank you for the feedback. Compare the value is it inside or outside foreach ?

Comment: Inside, because you need to do this for each single record.

Comment: @CBroe . Please check my updated code . I manage to display Account Number once and category works fine. But I want to display Amount like Account number too. Thanks. I'm not sure where to add third td tag inside the code.

Comment: Outputting `</td></tr>` when the account numbers don’t match makes little sense - you don’t want to end the current table row at that point, but output an empty table cell instead. Have a look at Javed’s answer - setting a flag to determine whether to output account number and amount is the easiest way to go about this.

Comment: In your updated snippet  you have a typo at `$selectionC`.  And you have no ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

Create new array,reorder and modified it.

PHP

```
<?php

$arr_old = array(
    0 => array('ACCOUNT_NUMBER' => '1001', 'CATEGORY' => 'Apple', 'AMOUNT' => '30.00'),
    1 => array('ACCOUNT_NUMBER' => '1001', 'CATEGORY' => 'Mango', 'AMOUNT' => '30.00'),
    2 => array('ACCOUNT_NUMBER' => '1001', 'CATEGORY' => 'Blueberry', 'AMOUNT' => '30.00'), 
    3 => array('ACCOUNT_NUMBER' => '1002', 'CATEGORY' => 'Durian', 'AMOUNT' => '40.00'),
    4 => array('ACCOUNT_NUMBER' => '1002', 'CATEGORY' => 'Pineapple', 'AMOUNT' => '40.00'),
    5 => array('ACCOUNT_NUMBER' => '1002', 'CATEGORY' => 'Lime', 'AMOUNT' => '40.00'),
    6 => array('ACCOUNT_NUMBER' => '1003', 'CATEGORY' => 'Lemon', 'AMOUNT' => '50.00'),
    7 => array('ACCOUNT_NUMBER' => '1002', 'CATEGORY' => 'Jackfruit', 'AMOUNT' => '40.00'), 
    8 => array('ACCOUNT_NUMBER' => '1003', 'CATEGORY' => 'Orange', 'AMOUNT' => '50.00')
);

$arr = array();

foreach($arr_old as $key => $item)
{
    if(!array_key_exists($item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER'],$arr)){
        // Add new data in array with ACCOUNT_NUMBER as an index
        $arr[$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']][$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']]['ACCOUNT_NUMBER'] = $item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER'];
        $arr[$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']][$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']]['CATEGORY'] = $item['CATEGORY'];
        $arr[$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']][$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']]['AMOUNT'] = $item['AMOUNT'];
    }else{
        // Only alter category index
        $arr[$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']][$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']]['CATEGORY'] .= ",".$item['CATEGORY'];
    }


}

ksort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>ACCOUNT_NUMBER</td>";
echo "<td>CATEGORY</td>";
echo "<td>AMOUNT</td>";
echo "</tr>";
foreach($arr as $key => $item){

    $xpl = explode(",",$item[$key]['CATEGORY']);
    $n_category = "";
    foreach($xpl as $b => $a){
        $n_category .= ($b!=0) ? "<br>".$a : $a ;
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$item[$key]['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$n_category."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$item[$key]['AMOUNT']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    // print_r($item);
}
echo "</table>";
```

And the example here : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfd9579dfe39ab9fba6922209ceec1a33debbfc6

Comment: This does not attempt to write an html table.

Comment: Of course there is no html table here. I just give an example and idea. just edit at foreach(before/after) to put the table and the rest. Don't expect that I need to put all in there. From last result(echo), you should already got what to do next.

Comment: Your code is what I want synz. But how to add tr and td tag on it ? each account one row of table cell . Thanks again.

Comment: at last echo. put `<tr><td>echo $item[$key]['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']." - ".$item[$key]['CATEGORY']." - ".$item[$key]['AMOUNT']." \n";</td></tr> `seperate them.

Comment: @synz. Nice. One last question. How to add br tag on the Category column after comas ? sorry too many question.

Comment: because i tried to str_replace(',' '<br/>', $item[$key]['COLLATERAL_CATEGORY']) into echo . it didnt work.

Comment: All of the php processes in this solution are more appropriately done in the query as demonstrated by @david.  I do not recommend this multi-loop solution.

Comment: Why would you use , as glue only to replace it later -- this is not a professional-grade / direct solution.

Comment: If that question is for me. 1st - @Rozaimi need in CATEGORY with `,` result. So I just give him an example how to archive that. 2nd - In foreach I change it to `,` to `<br>` because he asked after that. If not, I already put it when I insert into new array. 3rd - Maybe @Rozaimi need to do something else with that kind of result. I don't know and I won't asked what he intended to do next, with that result. And yeah group in query more better. But here, I just want to give him another solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$account_numbers = array();
foreach($sql as $row) {
    $display = FALSE;
    if(!in_array($row["ACCOUNT_NUMBER"], $account_numbers)) {
        $account_numbers[] = $row["ACCOUNT_NUMBER"];
        $display = TRUE;
    } ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $display ? $row["ACCOUNT_NUMBER"] : ""; ?>
        </td>
        <td><?php echo $row["CATEGORY"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["AMOUNT"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php }
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback javed. I'll have it try first. I'll let you know.

Comment: Hi Javed. Its working. Account Number and Amount column can display once while the category display the looping value. But how to make it display on single tr tag row for each account ?

Comment: I have downvoted because this answer does not provide the desired result and is a code-only answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query into this one

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(CATEGORY) AS categories
FROM TABLE
WHERE COLUMN = 'Fruits'
GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER
```

The full code

```
<?php
  $sqlTxt = "SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(CATEGORY) as categories FROM table WHERE column = 'Fruits' GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER";
  $sql = ORACLE::getInstance()->FetchArray($sqlTxt);
  if(count($sql) > 0)
  {
    foreach($sql as $row)
    {
?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row["ACCOUNT_NUMBER"] ;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["categories"]; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row["AMOUNT"]; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
  }
?>
```

`GROUP_CONCAT(CATEGORY)` will get all categories according to the ACCOUNT_NUMBER.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately my sql query is to complicated and have multiple layer. Thats why I want to execute it inside foreach only. Thanks again.

Comment: Your question does not show any evidence of complication.  Barring the missing `SEPARATOR` this is what I would recommend.  If this is not good enough, please explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Your entire process of grouping the fruit names and gluing them together with `,<br>` **can** and **should** be performed in the query as a matter of best practice.  Sure, the resultset can be iterated and php functions can be used to prepare the values, but it will be less efficient and result in far more lines of code.

The most direct and professional solution that I can offer you based on your posted details is:

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tWn3qKrpHzV86Yq8k8WhCq/2

```
SELECT `ACCOUNT_NUMBER`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(`CATEGORY` ORDER BY `CATEGORY` ASC SEPARATOR ',<br>') AS `CATEGORY`,
        MAX(`CATEGORY_AMOUNT`) AS `CATEGORY_AMOUNT`
FROM `table`
WHERE `column` = 'Fruits'
GROUP BY `ACCOUNT_NUMBER`
ORDER BY `ACCOUNT_NUMBER`
```

Depending on your database settings, you might not need to use `MAX()`, but for my online demo it was necessary.

Notice that in my demo link, I shuffled the rows and added a vegetable row.  If needed for your project, `GROUP_CONCAT()` also offers `DISTINCT` if you only want unique values to be grouped together.

If this solution is not suitable for your actual project requirements, then please take the time to update your question details to more accurately reflect what you are working with.

With your resultset fully prepared, you can iterate it normally to display as an html table.

Comment: @Rozaimi It is very important to me (and other users in this community that care deeply about site content quality) that you are provided the best possible solution, and that you understand it, and that it is indicated as the best solution.  Indicating the best solution is important because existing pages are often used to close new duplicate questions.  When I am choosing older pages to close new pages with, I need to be confident that new researchers will be able to find the best solution.  The green tick draws a lot of attention, so I believe it should be on the "best" answer.