# How to echo number format grouping array inside foreach using PHP ?

Tags: php, number-formatting

My question is referring to my previous question in this link [How to echo specific multiple same records only once using foreach loops in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51925670/how-to-echo-specific-multiple-same-records-only-once-using-foreach-loops-in-php) .

This is my current code

**Code :**

```
$sqlTXT  = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
$arr_old = DB::getInstance()->FetchArray($sqlTXT);

if(count($arr_old) > 0)
{
        $arr = array();

        foreach($arr_old as $key => $item)
    {
        if(!array_key_exists($item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER'], $arr))
        {
            $arr[$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']][$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']]['ACCOUNT']   = $item['ACCOUNT'];
            $arr[$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']][$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']]['CATEGORY']  = $item['CATEGORY'];
            $arr[$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']][$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']]['VALUE']     = $item['VALUE'];
            $arr[$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']][$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']]['FUND']      = $item['FUND'];
            $arr[$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']][$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']]['AMOUNT']    = $item['AMOUNT'];
        }
        else
        {
            $arr[$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']][$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']]['CATEGORY']   .= ",".$item['CATEGORY'];
            $arr[$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']][$item['ACCOUNT_NUMBER']]['VALUE']      .= ",".$item['VALUE'];
        }
    }

    ksort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);

    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>ACCOUNT</td>";
    echo "<td>CATEGORY</td>";
    echo "<td>VALUE</td>";
    echo "<td>FUND</td>";
    echo "<td>AMOUNT</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    foreach($arr as $key => $item)
    {

        // Display Category
        $xpl = explode(",",$item[$key]['CATEGORY']);
        $n_category = "";
        foreach($xpl as $b => $a){
            $n_category .= ($b!=0) ? "<br>".$a : $a ;
        }

        // Display Value
        $trl = explode(",",$item[$key]['VALUE']);
        $n_value = "";
        foreach($trl as $c => $d){
            $n_value .= ($c!=0) ? "<br>".$d : $d ;

            // $new = number_format($n_value, 2, '.', ',');
        }

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$item[$key]['ACCOUNT']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$n_category."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$new."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item[$key]['FUND']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$item[$key]['AMOUNT']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

}
```

And the output as shown as below.

**Output :**

```
ACCOUNT         CATEGORY            VALUE           FUND            AMOUNT 

0001            Category1           10000           BIN         300,000.00
                Category2               0 
                Category3             500
                Category4           15000


0002            Category1            8500           BIN          70,000.00
                Category2            7000
                Category3             100
                Category4               0
```

But my current issue is I can't convert the VALUE column into 2 decimals format. When I added code

```
$new = number_format($n_value, 2, '.', ',');
```

The output only shows the first value of array.

I hope that someone can help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert each value in the column independently. Try changing your foreach loop to this:

```
foreach($trl as $c => $d){
    if (is_numeric($d)) $d = number_format($d, 2, '.', ',');
    $n_value .= ($c!=0) ? "<br>".$d : $d ;
}
```